# How to send data from sale order line to invoice line in Odoo v12?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

How to send data from custom field in sale order line to another custom field in the invoice order line in Odoo 12? Which method should I edit?

I used these methods but dose not work with me

```
class sale_advance_payment_inherit(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'sale.advance.payment.inv'

    @api.multi
    def _create_invoice(self, order, so_line, amount):
        inv_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
        ir_property_obj = self.env['ir.property']

        account_id = False
        if self.product_id.id:
            account_id = self.product_id.property_account_income_id.id or self.product_id.categ_id.property_account_income_categ_id.id
        if not account_id:
            inc_acc = ir_property_obj.get('property_account_income_categ_id', 'product.category')
            account_id = order.fiscal_position_id.map_account(inc_acc).id if inc_acc else False
        if not account_id:
            raise UserError(
                _(
                    'There is no income account defined for this product: "%s". You may have to install a chart of account from Accounting app, settings menu.') %
                (self.product_id.name,))

        if self.amount <= 0.00:
            raise UserError(_('The value of the down payment amount must be positive.'))
        context = {'lang': order.partner_id.lang}
        if self.advance_payment_method == 'percentage':
            amount = order.amount_untaxed * self.amount / 100
            name = _("Down payment of %s%%") % (self.amount,)
        else:
            amount = self.amount
            name = _('Down Payment')
        del context
        taxes = self.product_id.taxes_id.filtered(lambda r: not order.company_id or r.company_id == order.company_id)
        if order.fiscal_position_id and taxes:
            tax_ids = order.fiscal_position_id.map_tax(taxes, self.product_id, order.partner_shipping_id).ids
        else:
            tax_ids = taxes.ids
        print ('fffffffffffffffffff')
        invoice = inv_obj.create({
            'name': order.client_order_ref or order.name,
            'origin': order.name,
            'type': 'out_invoice',
            'reference': False,
            'account_id': order.partner_id.property_account_receivable_id.id,
            'partner_id': order.partner_invoice_id.id,
            'partner_shipping_id': order.partner_shipping_id.id,
            'invoice_line_ids': [(0, 0, {
                'name': name,
                # 'tracking': so_line.tracking,
                # 'receiver_or_sender_customer': self.receiver_or_sender_customer,
                # 'courier_id': self.courier_id.id,
                # 'from_zone_id': self.from_zone_id.id,
                # 'to_zone_id': self.to_zone_id.id,
                # 'wight': self.wight,
                # 'wight_category_id': self.wight_category_id.id,
                # 'extra_wight_fees': self.extra_wight_fees,
                # 'cod': self.cod,
                # 'cod_fees': self.cod_fees,
                'origin': order.name,
                'account_id': account_id,
                'price_unit': amount,
                'quantity': 1.0,
                'discount': 0.0,
                'uom_id': self.product_id.uom_id.id,
                'product_id': self.product_id.id,
                'sale_line_ids': [(6, 0, [so_line.id])],
                'invoice_line_tax_ids': [(6, 0, tax_ids)],
                'analytic_tag_ids': [(6, 0, so_line.analytic_tag_ids.ids)],
                'account_analytic_id': order.analytic_account_id.id or False,
            })],
            'currency_id': order.pricelist_id.currency_id.id,
            'payment_term_id': order.payment_term_id.id,
            'fiscal_position_id': order.fiscal_position_id.id or order.partner_id.property_account_position_id.id,
            'team_id': order.team_id.id,
            'user_id': order.user_id.id,
            'comment': order.note,
        })
        invoice.compute_taxes()
        invoice.message_post_with_view('mail.message_origin_link',
                                       values={'self': invoice, 'origin': order},
                                       subtype_id=self.env.ref('mail.mt_note').id)
        return invoice

    @api.multi
    def create_invoices(self):
        sale_orders = self.env['sale.order'].browse(self._context.get('active_ids', []))

        if self.advance_payment_method == 'delivered':
            sale_orders.action_invoice_create()
        elif self.advance_payment_method == 'all':
            sale_orders.action_invoice_create(final=True)
        else:
            # Create deposit product if necessary
            if not self.product_id:
                vals = self._prepare_deposit_product()
                self.product_id = self.env['product.product'].create(vals)
                self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('sale.default_deposit_product_id', self.product_id.id)

            sale_line_obj = self.env['sale.order.line']
            for order in sale_orders:
                if self.advance_payment_method == 'percentage':
                    amount = order.amount_untaxed * self.amount / 100
                else:
                    amount = self.amount
                if self.product_id.invoice_policy != 'order':
                    raise UserError(_(
                        'The product used to invoice a down payment should have an invoice policy set to "Ordered quantities". Please update your deposit product to be able to create a deposit invoice.'))
                if self.product_id.type != 'service':
                    raise UserError(_(
                        "The product used to invoice a down payment should be of type 'Service'. Please use another product or update this product."))
                taxes = self.product_id.taxes_id.filtered(
                    lambda r: not order.company_id or r.company_id == order.company_id)
                if order.fiscal_position_id and taxes:
                    tax_ids = order.fiscal_position_id.map_tax(taxes, self.product_id, order.partner_shipping_id).ids
                else:
                    print ('assssssssssssssss')
                    tax_ids = taxes.ids
                context = {'lang': order.partner_id.lang}
                analytic_tag_ids = []
                for line in order.order_line:
                    analytic_tag_ids = [(4, analytic_tag.id, None) for analytic_tag in line.analytic_tag_ids]
                    tracking = line.tracking
                so_line = sale_line_obj.create({
                    'name': _('Advance: %s') % (time.strftime('%m %Y'),),
                    'price_unit': amount,
                    'product_uom_qty': 0.0,
                    'order_id': order.id,
                    'discount': 0.0,
                    # 'tracking': tracking,
                    'product_uom': self.product_id.uom_id.id,
                    'product_id': self.product_id.id,
                    'analytic_tag_ids': analytic_tag_ids,
                    'tax_id': [(6, 0, tax_ids)],
                    'is_downpayment': True,
                })
                del context
                self._create_invoice(order, so_line, amount)
        if self._context.get('open_invoices', False):
            return sale_orders.action_view_invoice()
        return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from [this method here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L1405):

```
@api.multi
def invoice_line_create(self, invoice_id, qty):
    """ Create an invoice line. The quantity to invoice can be positive (invoice) or negative (refund).
        .. deprecated:: 12.0
            Replaced by :func:`invoice_line_create_vals` which can be used for creating
            `account.invoice.line` records in batch
        :param invoice_id: integer
        :param qty: float quantity to invoice
        :returns recordset of account.invoice.line created
    """
    return self.env['account.invoice.line'].create(
        self.invoice_line_create_vals(invoice_id, qty))
```

So, make something like this:

```
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    @api.multi
    def invoice_line_create(self, invoice_id, qty):
        invoice_lines = super().invoice_line_create(invoice_id, qty)
        for invoice_line in invoice_lines:
            for sale_line in invoice_line.sale_line_ids:
                for move_line in sale_line.move_ids:
                    invoice_line.write({
                        'new_field': move_line.new_field,
                    })
        return invoice_lines
```